# How do I mark a Capybara feature test as pending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I expect these tests not to "FAIL", but be marked as pending. Perhaps I am not using pending or the correct directive for Capybara specifically?

```
feature 'Tenant Scoping ' do

  scenario "displays only Tenant A's things" do
    pending
  end

  scenario "displays only Tenant B's things" do
    pending
  end

end
```

Here's the output when run:

```
Tenant Scoping
  displays only Tenant A's things (FAILED - 1)
  displays only Tenant B's things (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) Tenant Scoping  displays only Tenant A's things FIXED
     Expected pending 'No reason given' to fail. No Error was raised.
     # ./spec/features/tenants/scopingtest_spec.rb:3

  2) Tenant Scoping  displays only Tenant B's things FIXED
     Expected pending 'No reason given' to fail. No Error was raised.
     # ./spec/features/tenants/scopingtest_spec.rb:7

Finished in 0.04047 seconds (files took 1.62 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of RSpec 3, pending examples are considered a failure if they pass. Try using `skip` instead of `pending` to completely skip those specs.

See [Notable Changes in RSpec 3](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#changes_to__semantics_and_introduction_of_) for more info.

Comment: It could be I'm missing something, but this isn't working for me.  These aren't specs, they're features.  If you replace `pending` in the OP code with `skip`, it will not skip the scenario. @typeoneerror, did you get this working the way you wanted?

Answer (score 14):

Just replace 'scenario' with 'xscenario'.

Only drawback is that it will mark the entire feature as pending, instead of each individual spec.  I have not found a way around this.